# Express.Router middleware is being called on all routes after routes are registered

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I have a simple app which has a login page and a section for authenticated users from where unauthenticated users are being redirected back to login. At the end of all my routes, I have `app.all('*', ...)` which returns 404 error page.

When I am authenticated, everything works fine, but if I log out and try to fetch unexisting route, I am redirected to the login page instead of getting 404 response.

I understand that this is because I added middleware which handles redirection but I would expect it to work only on routes specified in that one exact router - not in all routes (even the app-level ones) which are placed right after middleware.

The only solution I see at the moment is to use this authCheck middleware in every restricted route instead of registering it globally using `router.use` but I am still wondering if there is a better way?

```
const express = require('express')

module.exports = (app) => {
  const authRouter = express.Router()

  // ================================
  // ========= Public Routes ========
  // ================================
  app.get('/login', () => { /* ... login route */ })
  app.post('/login', () => { /* ... login route */ })

  // ====================================
  // ========= Restricted Routes ========
  // ====================================
  authRouter.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.isAuthenticated()
      ? next()
      : res.redirect('/login')
  })

  authRouter.get('/', () => { /* restricted route */ })

  // register restricted routes
  app.use(authRouter)

  // ========================================
  // ============ Other routes ==============
  // ========================================

  // error 404 route <--- this works only for authenticated users
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {

    res.status(404)
    res.render('error404')
  })
}
```

Thanks for any ideas..

Comment: Without changing any code, you could change the flow of execution to get it to work properly.

Comment: I tried to move app.get('*') to the top but it started returning error 404 on all routes.. How would you change the order?

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't recommend changing the order, as it would be confusing.  There is most likely a better way.

Comment: @JanJůna Your code should not depend on the order of middleware, better go for the generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can create an array of all URLs without auth and check inside middleware.

```
const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    /* Urls Without Auth */
    const withoutAuth = ['/login'];
    if (withoutAuth.includes(req.url) || req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
};

app.use(authMiddleware);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express')
// Note: FWIW I think it's better to organize your middleware
// into separate files and store them into separate directory
// So you could use it like that:
// const verifyAuthMiddleware = require('./middleware/verifyAuthMiddleware);
const verifyAuthMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    req.isAuthenticated()
      ? next()
      : res.redirect('/login')
  };

module.exports = (app) => {    
  // ================================
  // ========= Public Routes ========
  // ================================
  app.get('/login', () => { /* ... login route */ })
  app.post('/login', () => { /* ... login route */ })

  // ====================================
  // ========= Restricted Routes ========
  // ====================================    
  // You can add the middleware like that
  app.get('/', [verifyAuthMiddleware], () => { /* restricted route */ });

  // Or you can add a middleware to a group of routes like that
  app.use('/user', [verifyAuthMiddleware]);
  // And then every route that starts with "/user" uses the middleware
  app.get('/user/settings', () => {});
  app.get('/user/wallet', () => {});
  app.get('/user', () => {});
  app.post('/user/wallet', () => {});
  // etc


  // ========================================
  // ============ Other routes ==============
  // ========================================

  // error 404 route <--- this works only for authenticated users
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {

    res.status(404)
    res.render('error404')
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your replies. In the end, I did it like this:

```
function authCheck (req, res, next) {
    return req.isAuthenticated()
        ? next()
        : res.redirect('/login')
}

// Product routes
const prodRouter = express.Router()
prodRouter.get('/', products.getlist)
prodRouter.get('/:uuid/:tab?', products.getbyId)
prodRouter.post('/:uuid/:tab?', products.update)

// Register product routes
app.use('/products', [authCheck, prodRouter])

// For all other routes return 404 error page
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).render('error404')
})
```

With this approach, the `authCheck` middleware is being used only on `/product` routes so when I access `/missing-page` I get correctly the `Error 404 page`.

Comment: You might want to use `app.use('*', ...` rather than `app.get('*', ...`.